# ClearInterval not working not matter what

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, intervals

Iam trying to apply a new order by filter in my eccommerce. I need that when the handleOptionClick function is executed and option.value is like in the code, the interval keeps executing "CustomOrder" and when option.value its something else stops the interval. The thing is nothing i try seems to work.

```
  function setOrderCustom(opt){
    const intervaloOrder = setInterval(() => {
      if(opt){
        console.log('execution');
        CustomOrder()

      } else {
        console.log('why doesnt stop??');
        clearInterval(intervaloOrder)
      }
    }, 1000)

  }

  const handleOptionClick = () => {
    console.log('option.value: ', option.value);
    if(option.value === "priceByUnit:asc"){
      //console.log('Ordenamiento custom');
      onItemClick()
      setOrderCustom(true)
    } else {
      setOrderCustom(false)
      onItemClick()
      setQuery({ order: option.value, page: undefined })
    }
  }
```

I try doing it with an useEffect without the dependency array but nothing.

Comment: Every time you call `setOrderCustom()` you create a new interval. Why do you expect to cancel the previous one?

Comment: I do it this way couse i have a "Show More" and a lazy loding app, so if the interval keeps running my products re-arrenge in the order i need. The thing is when i apply another option.value by clicking a dropdown difrent from "priceByUnit:asc" the interval keeps changing my products

Comment: so much wrong with this code, but one of the big issues is you have an if statement inside the interval loop, which can never change opt to false. its going to continuously run that loop and never stop.

Comment: Ohh i see, alright then i will try to find another way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot wrong with this code.

1. first of all, you are creating a new interval on click, which means if someone clicks the button 10 times, you are going to have 10 different threads going with each from running an infinite number of loops.
2. inside your interval is code that will run continuously with no way of changing "opt" to false:

   ```
   if(opt){
    console.log('execution');
    CustomOrder()

   } else {
    console.log('why doesnt stop??');
    clearInterval(intervaloOrder)
   }
   ```

that code above is going to keep running, over and over again.

I think what you want to do is `return intervaloOrder;` out of your function and then kill it from the outside code.

try something like this:

```
function setOrderCustom(){
  return setInterval(() => {
     CustomOrder();
  }, 1000)
}

const handleOptionClick = () => {
  let intervaloOrder = null;
  console.log('option.value: ', option.value);
  if(option.value === "priceByUnit:asc"){
  onItemClick()
  intervaloOrder = setOrderCustom();
} else {
  clearInterval(intervaloOrder);
  onItemClick()
  setQuery({ order: option.value, page: undefined })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think thats the solution but im to noob to solve it. Im trying to return de interval and then kill it ass you say but i cant do it.

Comment: not sure if that will work or not, but maybe start with that

Comment: I did exactly that thanks to what you explained to me, thanks! but it doesnt work ether! I will try your code maybe its magic. jajajaj

Comment: No, that didnt work ether, i just cant belive it!